# Android: Using an intent to start any activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have been working on an application that has a bunch of formulas in it. The user can select which formula they need to use, input the numbers/variables, and the program will return whatever answer they are looking for. Each formula has its own class and since there are so many classes I sorted them into separate packages.

**For Example**, I might have **3 packages** (*Volume*, *Area*, and *Main*).

- In the *Volume* package, I might have **2 classes** (*Cube_Volume*, and *Sphere_Volume*).
- In the *Area* package, I might have **3 classes** (*Square_Area*, *Circle_Area*, and *Triangle_Area*).
- In the *Main* package, I might have **1 class** (*Main_Activity*).

I am currently trying to allow the user to bookmark their favorite formulas. If a user is in the *Sphere_Volume* class, they can bookmark that class. How I am currently attempting to do this is when the user chooses to bookmark the class, the application saves the string returned by this code.

```
this.getLocalClassName()
```

The string that is saved (I am using an SQL database to store the string) will look something like this:

```
com.example.area.Triangle_Area
```

The bookmarks that the user saves (like the one shown above) are displayed in a *Listview* in the *Main_Activity* class. Obviously, when the user clicks on a bookmark in the *Listview*, I would like the program to start the corresponding activity.

So finally, the question is: How can I use an Intent to start any activity in any other package when the string provided is something like ***com.example.area.Triangle_Area***?

Thanks for any and all answers! Please comment if I need to elaborate more on my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Intent` constuctor accepts the component class as its parameter, it's as simple as this:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Class.forName("com.example.area.Triangle_Area"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct answer! Just to clarify for anyone who is gonna use this answer, you can replace "com.example.area.Triangle_Area" with any string variable that equals  getLocalClassName(). Thanks again!