# how to pass Intent to new activity from firebase recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android development using Firebase. I get stuck in passing intent to new activity. I want to pass url and url1 to new activity when I click a particular card in recycler view.

Here is my code

**MainActivity**

```
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("project").child("electronics");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Project,BlogViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Project, BlogViewHolder>(
            Project.class,
            R.layout.card,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            myRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Project model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setProjectName(model.getProjectName());
            viewHolder.setUrl1(model.getUrl1());

            progressDialog.hide();
        }

    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public  static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView project1;
    ImageView imageview;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        project1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.projectImage);

    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        project1.setText(projectName);
    }

    public void setUrl1(String url1) {
        Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(url1)
                .into(imageview);
    }
```

**Project.java**

```
public class Project {
private  String projectName,url,url1;

public Project() {
}

public Project(String projectName, String url, String url1) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.url = url;
    this.url1 = url1;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrl1() {
    return url1;
}

public void setUrl1(String url1) {
    this.url1 = url1;
}}
```

Here is my Firebase Database
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYaHe.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Using an intent to start any activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959496/android-using-an-intent-to-start-any-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Bundle.

you get model.getUrl() in String and use [bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass what you want.

in your onClick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case xxxx:
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, nextActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String value = model.getUrl();
            bundle.putString(key, value);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

and In your nextActivity, you need to catch your bundle .

```
 private void getIntentData() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)
        Strin url = bundle.getString(key);
}
```

Comment: how to pass bundle in onClick

Comment: where is your onClick method?

Comment: itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), projectView.class);

                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


in intent i want to pass intent.putExtra(PROJECT_URL, project.getUrl()); this